# Blender getting very slow in handling large data?

Tags: geometry

I have a scene having 54000 planes in it. Blender is responding very slowly to the actions performed on this scene. Even the simple view changing operations done using middle mouse button are responding very slowly. And when i try to render them , blender stops working.

I think this is happening because of such large no. of planes having no connectivity between them at all, but 54000 planes is a very small number.

Can anyone tell me the exact reason of this problem and how to correct it to make blender more responsive with so many no. planes?

Comment: 54000 separate objects is actually a huge number of individual objects - try joining them all together as one object.

Comment: actually i am trying to render a point cloud in blender, this is the only method coming to my mind as of now to render points as planes. can you suggest any other way?

Comment: I would say that there is not real fix for this. Blender viewport is outdated and can't handle as many polygons as modern viewports. Try setting the maximum draw type to Bounds.

Comment: Also, try turning off `Outline selected` in the view settings, because atm, Blender will draw the object twice to get the outline.

Comment: Can you not join the objects together? Or is it animated? The best solution would be to use particles some how, but I don't know any point cloud importers that can do that (I don't know any point cloud importers at all)

Comment: @ZeroGravity You can also try halos.. But could you explain why joining the separate plane objects into a single object will not work?

Comment: @GregZaal & gandalf3 , i cant join these points to form a mesh because, these point clouds are constructed using computer vision techniques and have large whole at some places and joining them creates incorrect models of the real world objects that they represent. So i wanted to render them as splats, not as a mesh.

Comment: We mean "joining them" as in selecting them all and Ctrl+J - this won't change the mesh at all, simply combine them into one object to be handled as a whole

Comment: @GregZaal thanks, joining them in a single object worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question you asked is that 54000 individual objects is significantly different from 54000 polygons, so it's not surprising that Blender is having trouble with that many individual objects. There are some ways to [improve viewport performance](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?257323-What-everybody-needs-to-know-about-Blender-Viewport-performance) like turning on VBOs in the user preferences, but I don't think any of them will be terribly helpful at this point.

If all the planes were joined into one object, it'd probably perform much better, but it doesn't seem like that would be very helpful, for what you're doing.

The answer to the question you didn't ask ;-) is that this is a really expensive way to render a point cloud in Blender. There are two tools that will probably be very useful to you. [One will get point clouds into Blender](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/09/25/getting-point-clouds-into-blender/), and the other [will skin point clouds in Blender](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/12/python-script-point-cloud-skinner/). And this will probably be much more workable than your current solution ;-)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi!! @Matt, I joined all the polygons into a single object , now blender handles them easily without lagging behind. Now all the faces are in 1 single material color , what if i want to add a different face color to all faces?

Comment: If you create multiple materials for that object, you can select certain faces and click `Assign` to make those faces use that material instead. It can be a little tedious, but that may be your only option. If you're still trying to render a point cloud, there might be a better way to do that than using individual planes.

Comment: I looked for other alternate option to render a colored point cloud in blender, the link that you suggested gets only the point cloud data without any color and moreover do not show anything when rendered....